# Unable to recieve gyroscope data via Bluetooth LE, from an Arduino onto my iPhone App (iOS, Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, arduino, bluetooth, gyroscope

I currently am making a test iOS app that communicates with my Arduino Uno board over bluetooth.
I am using an HM-10 BLE module, and an MPU-6050 gyroscope & accelerometer.

I started the project by attempting to toggle an LED on and off, which is working fine.

Now, I would like to have the current xyz values of the gyroscope displayed on my iPhone.

It seems much of the work needs to be done in the inside the didUpdateValueFor function. Then use the data from there to update a text field.

I am testing by writing out only the x value of the gyroscope right now. It displays properly on the arduino serial monitor, and it would also display when I connect via bluetooth to my PC.

```
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        if characteristic.uuid == peripheralManager.hm10CharacteristicUUID {
            debugPrint("Writing Data")
            
            let myData = characteristic.value
            let rollText = String(data: myData!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? "roll not found"
            debugPrint(rollText)
        }
    }
```

The output of this code just prints "roll not found", over and over, like the gyro data prints out to the serial monitor

Would greatly appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Is your data a utf8 encoded string?  What if you just print the bytes in your data?  What are you receiving?

Comment: convert data to array of Uint8 (bytes)

Comment: If i just print out 'myData', it outputs 'Optional(1 bytes). 
The type outputs 'Swift.Optional<Foundation.Data>

This means i need to convert the bytes to something readable? Such as Uint8 as was mentioned?

Comment: Converted the incoming data to NSData, and its returning things such as '<ac>', '<ab>', '<aa>' .. 
Not sure how to convert to a format that will display the positive and negative integers I am expecting